# Netplan stops creating bond

Tags: networking, netplan, network-bonding

I've been running a home build home lab server for file sharing.  It worked perfectly until 5 days ago.  For no apparent reason, netplan stopped creating the 802.3ad bond0 network for my intel (pt) dual nic.  After some testing, the nic is fine and so is the switch.  I could issue commands to bond and enslave the ports by hand, but netplan gave up the ghost and refused to do so.  I was able to uninstall netplan and reconfigure using ifupdown instead.   There is a third port that I use as well on another nic that is used for management network functions - which is working fine.  I have another server as well that uses 2x dual bonded (bond0 and bond1) and copied/ modded the config yaml file just to be closer in comparison.  I tried reinstalling networkd, netplan.io, and ifenslave, and verified that bonding kernel module is installed and loads during boot.
Has anyone run into this before?  I'd like to revert back because I generally like netplan.io.  I'm up and running though, but would like some insights if anyone has any.

Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Answer (score 1):

We tried many solutions from many sites, but only installing the package `network-manager` and  using `NetworkManager` as `renderer` in `netplan` fixed this problem.

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Comment: I'm having an issues with netplan being unable to use the eth1 adapter in the bonding mode after some inactivity of this adapter (I am manually switching between eth0 and eth1 depending on usage). The adapter is up and works fine, but even after manual unplug it is still not responding. After removing the bonding it starts working again with no issues.
I found your answer when searched for this problem. I will see tomorrow if that also helped in my case.